# SQL Command to delete from table where data id is in two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, phpstorm

I am trying to delete a row in i.e. table 2 where the id is copied from table 1 query. I want to delete this row from table 2 and also from table 1 but I am having an issue where the command I have used all work but it does not seem delete from the tables. I believe this might be because of the relationship the tables have(I used mysql workbench to make the DB design)

I used this command :

```
delete
from doctorsTable
where Users_idUser in (select Users_idUser from Users where idUser = 20)
```

[image]

[image]

This is the relation : 
[image]

As mentioned, I am trying to delete the row from doctorsTable with Users_idUser=20 and automatically it would delete from Users table idUser also with 20. I have tried the above command, it seems to run but its not really deleting the rows . please help !

Comment: **1)** In sub-query `(select Users_idUser from Users where idUser = 20)` there is no `Users_idUser` field in `Users` table. Maybe you meant to use `idUser` instead? **2)** Such complex command does not make much sense to me if all you want is to delete a record from `doctorsTable`. IF (only if) I understand your tables and their relations correctly .. why not use `delete from doctorsTable where Users_idUser = 20` directly?

Comment: hi @LazyOne I have tried that but that also seems to not delete the row from doctorsTable. I fixed my sub-query but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to delete all rows with idUser from both tables with one statement.

You can do so by joining and deleting them like:

```
DELETE doctorsTable, Users
FROM doctorsTable
INNER JOIN Users ON doctorsTable.Users_idUser = Users.idUser
WHERE doctorsTable.Users_idUser = 20
```

In the DELETE line, you specify the table(s) from which to delete matching rows.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do and your code seems right but it is not deleting the rows. Could this be due to the table relations?

Comment: @Aboogie 1) Are you sure it's not deleting? I mean -- try Refresh button few times (on table view) -- just in case 2) Usually mysql should respond with "xx rows affected" or something similar -- do you see any of such messages? P.S. It may not deleting records from `Users` table because that table may have references to other tables?

Comment: i updated the code, this one should work. i changed the table in the where condition.

Comment: @buddy_casino where is the updated command? if you mean the one up there, it still doesn't work ...

Comment: @Aboogie so as LazyOne mentioned: What does mysql tell you about the execution? are there any constraints that keep mysql from deleting from doctorsTable?

Comment: the command and output : sql> DELETE doctorsTable, Users
FROM doctorsTable
INNER JOIN Users ON doctorsTable.Users_idUser = Users.idUser
WHERE doctorsTable.Users_idUser = 23
[2016-03-19 18:33:04] completed in 348ms

Comment: @Aboogie And what does `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` tell you about the number of rows affected? Did you check if the rows with idUser 23 remain in both tables?

Comment: I believe the problem is that I am not calling the full database name and tables and id before using them. I delete from both tables but I had to use the database.table before the command could be recognized. So i did the same thing with the code above wrote DELETE iot_pd_testing.doctorsTable, iot_pd_testing.Users
FROM iot_pd_testing.doctorsTable
INNER JOIN iot_pd_testing.Users ON iot_pd_testing.doctorsTable.Users_idUser = iot_pd_testing.Users.idUser
WHERE iot_pd_testing.doctorsTable.Users_idUser = 24; but there is an error : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I guess Ill just delete them alone one table at a time!

Comment: @Aboogie may it be that you have a foreign key constraint like `FOREIGN KEY(Users_idUser) REFERENCES Users.(idUser) ON DELETE CASCADE)` on table `doctorsTable` ? If so you can easily delete the rows (i.e. with id=23) from `Users` table only and `ON DELETE CASCADE` will delete related rows in `doctorsTable` automatically.

Comment: how do you use delete cascade with the above command you wrote @buddy_casino?

Comment: you should check your table definition syntax with `SHOW CREATE TABLE  doctorsTable`. What does it tell you about your foreign keys?

Comment: it says CONSTRAINT `fk_doctorsTable_Users` FOREIGN KEY (`Users_idUser`) REFERENCES `Users` (`idUser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Comment: so there must be another table referencing `doctorsTable` (f.e. doctorsTable.id_doctorsTable field) and holding rows with matching id. this would explain the message "Cannot delete ... a **parent** row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Comment: @Aboogie Based your model screenshot I may say that you have another relation to another table (that suspicious part of the dark line on the right side of the "doctorsTable" box) -- maybe it;s linked to some "Doctors" table?

Comment: its linked to another table which is the patient table.

Comment: Ah, i see: With this constraint, you have to delete them manually, the rows from `doctorsTable`first, and then the rows from `Users` table. Because of this constraint, the `DELETE` might be rejected, see the explanation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) under **Referential Actions**.  The only way to do the delete in one statement is to modify the constraint.